# ca. 1984 movie of boys flying on Space Shuttle

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify an early / mid 80s movie from the following description of the trailer.

It premiered in West Germany in the summer of 1984 or 1985 - I remember biking in summer heat past the poster at our local cinema on my way home from school. I always wanted to see it but didn't ask.

The trailer went like this:

A group of (Caucasian, dark haired) boys (all pre-pubescent with not a single girl present, so it's not [Space Camp](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091993/)) gets to visit the cockpit of a Space Shuttle that sits fueled up on a launch pad. They're all dressed in blue flight suits with white t-shirts underneath. NASA crew shuts the doors and leaves.

Meanwhile, in a (fully staffed) command center, the Flight Director (FD) is alerted by some crew member that one of the booster rockets is overheating, as indicated by a quite distinct display: the spacecraft's outline in black lines on white (the display protrudes notably whereas other controls don't, making it look like an added on prop). The left-hand booster's outline is slowly filling up with color from bottom to top in a gradient that goes from green (bottom) to red (top). FD decides to launch the shuttle; someone hits a button and on the display the right-hand booster quickly fills with the same color gradient. The boys are told to take seats and buckle up. One of them however runs towards the back shouting "I can fix this!" while the others call on him to sit.

The trailer closes with briefly showing fix-this on an untethered EVA with an [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Maneuvering_Unit).

Comment: It is "Space Camp", with the problem with the engine, with that "color filling", and with the launch.

Comment: Absolutely "Space Camp" for the cringeworthy booster thing.

Comment: Given it was a trailer, the marketing in your country may have focused on the male actors and not the female, as a way to target a specific audience - which is why you specifically remember an all male crew.  Including females in the trailer may have been perceived to put off boys from going to see it.  Lots of films and series (and indeed toys) over the years have had the female cast downplayed for this specific reason.

Comment: Sorry @Moo, but [here's the German trailer for Space Camp](https://youtu.be/ktIeObBeBl4) and it doesn't omit female protagonists. Now it could be argued that it's not the one screened back then, but the display with the shuttles' outline and the FD look very different from what I saw back then.

Answer (score 26):

I am sure it is [Space Camp](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091993/) anyway.

> The young attendees of a space camp find themselves in space for real
> when their shuttle is accidentally launched into orbit.

See [Movie trailer](https://youtu.be/d-Et5PoV2jE?t=95), it shows exactly the same engine problem:

[image]

[Full movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEoQF4dic4g)

Comment: The only place in the known universe where it was referred to as "Booster B". Sigh.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Next you'll be telling us NASA doesn't have AI-driven robots that can trivially override CAPCOM computers either...

Comment: @Machavity Of course they do!   Where do you think the inspiration for R2D2 came from?

Comment: Sorry, @yaroslav-kornachevskyi, but as I said the display of the shutle was black on black, not green on black, it wasa small display in a console and not a separate monitor ,the booster with the problem was the left one and not the right one and the color filling was a gradient from green to red and not solid red.